# JQuery and Dynamic sub list on separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a sub listview page separate from the typical caged one:

This is what I'm trying to do:

STEP1 - Loops gets all the data and creates the list in the listview:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var data = {"id":[{"id":1,"title":"title1","bodytext":"sometext 1"},{"id":2,"title":"title2","bodytext":"sometext 2"},{"id":3,"title":"title3","bodytext":"sometext 3"}
                   }]

    var output = ''

    $.each(data.id, function(index, value){

       output += '<li><a href="#mypage">'+value.title+'</a></li>';

       $('#mypage').text(value.title); //will this be different for each item?

    });

    $('#mylistview').html(output).listview('refresh'); //Refresh the listview with new added data

});
```

STEP 2:

The listview now looks like this:

```
<ul id-"mylistview">
   <li><a href="populate_#mypage_with_data_from_item_1">title1</a></li>
   <li><a href="populate_#mypage_with_data_from_item_2">title2</a></li>
   <li><a href="populate_#mypage_with_data_from_item_3">title3</a></li>
</ul>
```

STEP 3:

I have a pre-made template:

```
<div id="mypage">
Data from selected item goes here
</div>

So, if I click on list item 1 mypage will look like this:

<div id="mypage">
Sometext 1
</div>

or if item 2 is clicked:

<div id="mypage">
Sometext 2
</div>
```

My problem is that  no matter which item I click in the listview I always get the data from item 1.

How can I maker it so each item has it's own data displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = {"ids":[
         {"id":1,"title":"title1","bodytext":"sometext 1"},
         {"id":2,"title":"title2","bodytext":"sometext 2"},
         {"id":3,"title":"title3","bodytext":"sometext 3"}]};

    var output = '',
        myPages = $('.mypage'),
        container = $('#mylistview');

    $.each(data.ids, function(index, value){
       output += '<li><a href="#mypage">'+value.title+'</a></li>';
       myPages.eq(index).text(value.bodytext);
    });

    container.html(output);

    container.on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var links = container.find('a');
        alert(myPages.eq(links.index(this)).text());
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mDnE6/

Comment: Yes, the ID is the same for all but shouldn't this:  $('#bodytext').text(value.body); make the bodytext unique?

Comment: @Satch3000 I hardly understand logic from provided code snippet, but `id` must be unique, if you want not unique, then use `class`. In your example you will replace text for `#bodytext` in loop, it has no sense.

Comment: As the Div #mysubpage is pre-created and I only want to change the text on it I cannot change the link to say... <a href="#mysubpage'+value.id+'">

Comment: @Satch3000 Ok, look at my example [jsfiddle.net/VqxKr/](http://jsfiddle.net/VqxKr/). You trying something like this? Also look at your `$.each(data.id,...)` you trying to iterate through `id` prop, this is array?

Comment: Hi I've redone my question...hope it's explained now...thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is because you can only have one id call "pagetitle"

Comment: Code amended. Please check again

Comment: Could you give us your code rather than pieces of it. This is quite unclear what you are trying to do and how.

Comment: OK, I've redone my question. Hope its more understandable now.

Comment: @Satch3000 In second code block `output` not used anywhere, you always set `$('#bodytext').text(value.body);` and you use `#bodytext` in loop.

Comment: Hi I've redone my question...hope it's explained now...thanks